Jackson's JsonSerializer don't work for deep-nested object hirarchies
For the serialization of Java object instances I use the Jackson Library and have built several JsonSerializers, which should individually check Player.class, Vehicle.class and Building.class and transform them accordingly. I registered the listeners as SimpleModules and then mapped the instances with convertValue() through the ObjectMapper.
However, the process actually works great. The mapper independently recognizes where the corresponding instances of the classes occur and passes them through the registered serializer.
My problem, however, is that it no longer works above a certain level of gradations. If the vehicles are directly in a list in the player object, they are serialized. However, if they are one level lower, namely in items of another list of the player instance (see in parkedVehicles), they are no longer recognized by the serializer.

        Player p = ...;
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(MapperFeature.REQUIRE_SETTERS_FOR_GETTERS, true);
        ObjectNode objectNode = mapper.createObjectNode();

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(Player.class, new PlayerSerialization());
        module.addSerializer(Building.class, new BuildingSerialization());
        module.addSerializer(Vehicle.class, new VehicleSerialization());
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        objectNode.set("player", mapper.convertValue(p, ObjectNode.class));


First of all, great job for the question it is very well redacted. Can you please show the code of BuildingSerialization?

And does Building have a public getter for it's parkedVehicles?  Will need more code to help resolve.

@AndrewS Thank you both! Building has a public getter for parkedVehicles (with @Getter by lombok). The vehicle information also gets printed, but the problem is, that it doesn't get polished/edited by the serializer. So the object just gets printed in its raw state.
@matteo-nnz The code for the BuildingSerialization is here.
Thank you in advance!

@Jonas please add it to the question because it's relevant to answer it. I can't open pastbin links as my company's firewall blocks it.

I've done some further research and tried out a bit and came to a new problem:
The converter/serializer seems to work as long as the corresponding object is directly passed to mapper.convertValue(). Any kind of nesting would result in an ignorance of the serializer. So for example:
objectNode.set("you", mapper.convertValue(event.getUser(), ObjectNode.class));

...wouldn't convert the nested user fields like headquarter. They just get default-printed. Meanwhile, if I use:
objectNode.set("you", mapper.convertValue(u.getHeadquarter(), ObjectNode.class));

...the converter would apply and convert the object as intended.
Here is an example, using StdConverter which doesn't work for any nested object of the registered listener type.
To conclude: My current approach using StdConverter doesn't work for any type of nested objects. They just get default-printed.
I'm very sorry for the confusion, my original post thus seems to be a bit wrong.
Do you know how to handle nested objects in order to convert them correctly? 
